# select spinner value according to condition

Tags: android, spinner

I have the following code:

```
private void spinnerValue(){
    spinnerwho=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinnerWho);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    adapter.add("A");
    adapter.add("B");
    spinnerwho.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinnerwho.setOnItemSelectedListener(spinnerlistener);
}
private OnItemSelectedListener spinnerlistener= new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        if(arg0.getSelectedItem().toString().contentEquals("A")){
            if (imagechanged){
                displayalert();
            }
            else{
                // Do some operation
            }
        }

        if(arg0.getSelectedItem().toString().contentEquals("B")){
            // do some operation            
        }
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};

private void displayAlert(DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener) {
    AlertDialog dlgAlertBox;
    AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dlgAlert.setMessage("data will be lost if you change value without saving. Continue?");
    dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Yes", listener);
    dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("No", listener);
    dlgAlert.setCancelable(true);           
    dlgAlertBox = dlgAlert.create();
    dlgAlertBox.show();
}
protected DialogInterface.OnClickListener BackButtonListenerforengineer = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
    {
        switch (which){
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE:
            // do some operation
            break;
        case DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE:
            dialog.dismiss();
// revert to previous selection
            /*Signature.this.spinnerwho.getAdapter();
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(Signature.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            adapter.clear();
            adapter.add("Tenant");
            adapter.add("Engineer");
            spinnerwho.setAdapter(adapter);
            spinnerwho.setSelection(1,true);

            spinnerwho.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);*/


            break;
    }
```

I select the value of spinner and checks the condition. When I tried to change the spinner items, it would show alert dialog with Yes and No buttons. Clicking Yes will change the value of spinner. If the user clicks No, then it should revert the spinner with previous selection. I tried clearing the spinner adapter and populated it with new values. But is not working. Can anyone help me by pointing out where I went wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

se following method to use spinner value.

```
private void addListenerOnSubjectSpinner() 
{
    spiSubject.setOnItemSelectedListener(new mySpinnerListener());      
}



class mySpinnerListener implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View v, int position,
            long id) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Subject is " +
                  parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        owq.setSubjectName(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) 
    {
        // Do nothing.
    }

}
```

In onCreate() call this two method.

```
addListenerOnSubjectSpinner();
```